# Running blockchain-wallet-service on a Heroku worker

Tags: node.js, django, heroku, blockchain

I'm trying to deploy my Django app on Heroku, that makes use of the Blockchain.info API V2 (https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3) and thus needs to run *blockchain-wallet-service* in the background, which in turn needs Node.js and npm installed.

On localhost, I have used this API successfully by running the service on my own machine, but I'm having trouble deploying to Heroku. Firstly, I assume I will need to run the service on a separate dyno, and that I will need node and npm installed on my instance.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this? I'm new to more advanced features of Heroku, I've tried to use the nodejs buildpack but I doubt this is the correct way. There is also this: https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/kmhouk/service-my-wallet-v3 which I've deployed as a separate app but I've failed to merge it in some way to my Django app.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue, bro, and i finally got some light in the end of the tunnel.

I've cloned the https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3 repository and deployed it to heroku and made some changes on "package.json" file. The problem is that (in heroku) you need to declare the dependencies on package file. I've added these lines:

```
"dependencies": {
    "blockchain-wallet-service": "~0.22.4",
}
```

and a script to test in the deploy:

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "blockchain-wallet-service -V"
}
```

Also, by cloning this repository, i needed to add this line too:

```
"license" : "(ISC OR GPL-3.0)",
```

hope it works for you